# How can I solve my "list_reverseiterator' object is not subscriptable" error?

Tags: python, list, loops, iterable

I've found this bit of code from a user here and edited it to get my game board:

```
rows = [[f'{(n+1) + (i*7):4}' for n in range(7)] for i in range(7)]
rows = reversed([reversed(rows[i]) if i%2 else rows[i] for i in range(len(rows))])

for row in rows:
    print(' | '.join(row))
```

This makes a perfect game board for me, 7 by 7:

```
  43 |   44 |   45 |   46 |   47 |   48 |   49
  42 |   41 |   40 |   39 |   38 |   37 |   36
  29 |   30 |   31 |   32 |   33 |   34 |   35
  28 |   27 |   26 |   25 |   24 |   23 |   22
  15 |   16 |   17 |   18 |   19 |   20 |   21
  14 |   13 |   12 |   11 |   10 |    9 |    8
   1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |    7
```

I can understand the code a little bit, I know that it uses a list generator and how it's reversing every other row..

But I would like to also be able to print the player's locations on the board. For example if Player1 was on position 6 on the board, I want to print out a new board but just replace the number 6 with "P1". I am running into the error `"TypeError: 'list_reverseiterator' object is not subscriptable"`

How can I do this with the above code? Do I need a different solution to draw the board?

Comment: Please then include the code that produced the exception, so we can correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers are generated in the first list comprehension, in the `f'..'` string:

```
f'{(n+1) + (i*7):4}'
```

This calculates the number as `(n + 1) + (i * 7)`, and formats it into a column of width 4. If you wanted to show something else here, you'd need to replace *that* with `P1`. That's easier if you first generate *just the numbers* with out any string formatting:

```
playerpos = 6
numbers = (((n+1) + (i*7) for n in range(7)) for i in range(7))
rows = [[f'{"P1" if pos == playerpos else pos:>4}' for pos in row] for row in numbers]
rows = reversed([reversed(rows[i]) if i%2 else rows[i] for i in range(len(rows))])
```

`numbers` is then a generator of generators that produces the numbers, and the first `rows` expression then produces a list of lists from that, formatting each number *or* the string `P1` if the number matches the player position.

I added a `>` to the formatting specification; numbers are right-aligned by default, but everything else is left-aligned. The `>` overrides that and right-aligns everything, putting the `P1` in the same position as the digits would be.

Demo:

```
>>> playerpos = 6
>>> numbers = (((n+1) + (i*7) for n in range(7)) for i in range(7))
>>> rows = [[f'{"P1" if pos == playerpos else pos:>4}' for pos in row] for row in numbers]
>>> rows = reversed([reversed(rows[i]) if i%2 else rows[i] for i in range(len(rows))])
>>> for row in rows:
...     print(' | '.join(row))
...
  43 |   44 |   45 |   46 |   47 |   48 |   49
  42 |   41 |   40 |   39 |   38 |   37 |   36
  29 |   30 |   31 |   32 |   33 |   34 |   35
  28 |   27 |   26 |   25 |   24 |   23 |   22
  15 |   16 |   17 |   18 |   19 |   20 |   21
  14 |   13 |   12 |   11 |   10 |    9 |    8
   1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |   P1 |    7
```

Comment: Excellent explanation and exactly what I was looking for. Can you also explain what the "f" is for in the expression f'...'?

Comment: @user766559: it's a formatted string literal; see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498